# Append image to rich text editor dosen't work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, rich-text-editor

This is how I append images to the post.  It displays in all browsers but IE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
image = '<img src="http://forum.site.com/.../<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>/question_reply_images/<?php echo $image_name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" />';
document.getElementById('editor1').innerHTML += '<span style="width:100%; float:left;"' + image + '</span>';
window.location = '#reply_textbox';
</script>
```

This is the process:  A user writes text in the textarea (Using WYSIWYG editor -- CKeditor) then will choose a file and upload it.  This is then appended to the end of the textarea.  This won't even display in IE.  The image is getting uploaded, but won't show in the textarea.

Comment: The ID of the textarea to append the image to.  It's a WYSIWYG editor e.g. CKeditor

Answer (score 2):

If "editor1" is a TEXTAREA, and you are putting the IMAGE tag **inside** it, this is invalid HTML anyway.  If that is what's going on, you're lucky that the image shows up in any browsers.  Make sure the IMAGE tag is contained by an element that is designed to hold such things.

*Additional info*

If you use the W3C validator, or search for the allowed children of TEXTAREA, you will find that it *does not allow* img or other tags inside of it.  Apart from your other problems, you should be surprised the non-IE browsers showed the image rather than upset that IE did not.

Comment: @Graham: Do not put the image **inside** the textarea.  Put the image **after** the textarea.

Comment: Good idea, but... how would it be included in the post when it's submitted?

Comment: @Graham:  I'm not sure what all you're dealing with.  Sounds like a different question to me.

Comment: Let me reiterate differently.  Only in IE... I can't append any HTML to the WYSIWYG e.g. CKeditor textarea.  The problem is when the user uploads an image / any html to the textarea.  What happens is the page is refreshed with the appended img tag / any html. In IE anything wrapped in HTML is completely ignored and not appended to the textarea.  Sorry, I'm probably explaining it weird.  Basically any thing wrapped in HTML is ignored when appended to a richtextarea  in IE.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out... For some reason replacing innerHTML with value did the trick for IE.